# How to install an extension on an existing container?

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker

I'm currently working on a linux VM and have postgres on an existing docker. I would like to be able to install the ogr_fdw extension on this existing docker but I'm having trouble understanding how I can achieve this action. Could someone help me figure out how to upload this extension to an existing postgres container?

Comment: `docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash` to get an interactive bash session, then from the bash you can install what you need (I guess `apt install`)

Comment: I can't use apt because I'm on alpine, not on a debian family linux

Comment: Ah ok, I wasnt sure, once you have the `bash` session you can use the tools of the VM (the concept is the same). With this approach you can update the running container but you might want to write your own Dockerfile to install the extension before running the container (so it is already there when you run it)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.